# Sort list based on comparator defined on another list using Guava Ordering

Tags: java, list, sorting, guava

I've two lists of same size : `List<A>listA`, `List<B>listB` that are completely independent of each other.

I'd like to sort `listA` based on how the elements move in `listB`.

Assume there's an imaginary connection b/w the two lists.

Eg:

```
listA = [a,b,c,d,e]
         | | | | |
listB = [j,g,h,k,i]
```

If the listB's comparator sorts it lexicographically, listA should be `b,c,e,a,d`

```
listA = [b,c,e,a,d]
         | | | | |
listB = [g,h,i,j,k]
```

I don't want to create a class that encapsulates both `A` & `B`.

I've come across [Ordering.explicit()](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit(java.util.List)) but not able to figure it out.

```
  private static  class ComparatorB implements Comparator<B> {
    @Override
    public int compare(B left, B right) {
      
    }
        
    }

Ordering<B> ordering = Ordering.from(new ComparatorB());
```

I'm not able to figure out what to pass to sort method. `listA.sort(????)`

Comment: What does "sort listA based on the ordering defined by a comparator on listB" mean? You can't sort A's using a comparator for B's. You will have to define that mapping.

Comment: Creating a class that encapsulates both A and B will be by far the easiest, most readable, and best-performing option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
listB.sort(new ComparatorB());
listA.sort(Ordering.explicit(listB)); // or possibly a mapped version
```

Or if you want to change a B-comparator into an A-comparator, you could do

```
listA.sort(Ordering.from(new ComparatorB()).onResultOf(a -> mapAtoB(a)))
```

Update after question update
You could do it like this:

```
Streams.zip(listA.stream(), listB.stream(), Pair::new)
                .sorted(Ordering.from(new ComparatorB()).onResultOf(Pair::getFirst))
                .map(Pair::getSecond)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm not sure if you'd count that `Pair` as "creating a class that encapsulates both A & B", but it's not clear why you don't want that anyway. This is probably your best bet.

Comment: I've updated the question. There isn't any mapping b/w `listA` and `listB`.

Comment: @duplex143 Oof... I'd say the easiest way would be to make a wrapper containing A's and B's (exactly like you say you don't want to do), then sort on their B properties and extract the A's again. If you really don't want to... perhaps make an index-to-element mapping for all B's, then sort, then somehow use `Ordering.explicit` to apply that same reordering to A? That sounds way more complicated than necessary, though.

Comment: I was under the impression that a simple one liner like you mentioned would be in Guava.  `listA.sort(Ordering.explicit(listB))` and somewhere pass the B's comparator.

Comment: @duplex143 There is, but you've explicitly excluded that option. In pseudo code: `zip(listA, listB).sortedWith(ComparatorB, it -> it.b).map(it -> it.a)`